# My GSuite routing options differ from the documentation

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I am trying to follow this document to set up routing:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084#initial-step

It says to go to the **Routing** section and click **Configure**.

However, MY routing section is completely different. It only has one field as displayed below.

[image]

I am trying to setup a catch-all that will go to an EXTERNAL address (a gmail address).

Comment: Hey, to those that voted to close, can you provide feedbacks in the comment? Maybe something to change in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may be on a free legacy G Suite domain which has an extremely limited set of controls and the majority of the documentation you will find does not apply to the license type you have. Head to this article for [Legacy Controls](https://support.google.com/a/topic/2683866) for Email Routing.